# add ~ to a relative url

Tags: asp.net, html

I used some relative url in my project like `<img src="../images/portal_header.jpg" .../>`, but our consultant insist to ask me change every url to `~/images/...`, and because they are html control, I have to add `runat="server"` tag for each one, So my question is that is it necessary? I have couple master page, it makes all the js link and css link unreached. Thanks

Comment: I suggest voicing your concerns to the consultant. If they have reasons for doing so, they will let you know. They probably just want the option of moving the file without the move breaking links inside it. They should have resolutions for the problems you run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control can live in any subfolder and be referenced by many different pages in many different subfolders.  `../` will not work in every case.

For that reason, you shuold resolve the URLs:

```
ResolveUrl("~/images/myimage.jpg")
```

And, no, you don't have to add `runat="server"`, you could do it like so:

```
<img src="<% =ResolveUrl("~/images/portal_header.jpg") %>" .../>
```

Comment: Yes, this resolves URLs and is a good way to do it. But IMHO it's not addressing the real question at hand, which I interpreted as "Do I need to programmatically resolve URLs or not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx

Comment: @kingdango - absolutely not. A code reviewer / architect can require that ALL controls and pages live one level deep, then ../images will always work.  But as the site develops, and people come and go, and requirements change, this may not be desirable requiremnt.  Better to refactor now while the code footprint is small than later when it's really big.

Comment: I have no disagreement with your last comment.  I personally choose to resolve URLs wherever possible but that's just my preference.  Of course I use MVC and Razor so this idea of runat="server" isn't really relevant anyway. :-)

Comment: @kingdango - agreed. At some point, someone will bury a page 3 levels deep and plop a control on it and suddenly, the image can't be found.  oops..

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly on context.  Using relative URLs works fine as long as the location of the dependent resources isn't expected to change.  Turning all of your image tags into controls does give you the benefit of using "~" (App Root) but it also adds overhead to processing on the server.

Your consultant is likely trying to protect you from a common problem.  All your relative links work fine in development ("http://localhost/site") but break when you move to production ("http://www.yourdomain.com/somelocation/").

Comment: @pita I obviously don't have access to your history of testing, etc but my answer is really trying to explain to you WHY the consultant may have suggested it and what the key differences are.  Neither option is "the only way to do it correctly" but one may be more correct depending on your situation.  Good luck!

Comment: @pita, the consultant is protecting you from future mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which ASP version you're working in, but I use `@Url.Content("~/relativepath")` for ASP4 using MVC3 w/Razor

or `<img src="@Url.Content("~/relativepath")" alt="" />`

Comment: FYI this example requires MVC and Razor.